# LayoutSubview messes up right bar button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a problem which I'm having a hard time to solve:
In my app, there is a custom UINavigationBar. If I override the `layoutSubviews` method, the horizontal position of my right bar button item is messed up, even if I do not do anything at all in the `layoutSubviews` method.

The bar button is added the following way in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(close)];`
```

My layoutSubviews method currently looks the following way:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

**Screenshot of the view hierarchy with layoutSubviews**

[image: messedUpViewHierarchy]

**Screenshot of the view hierarchy without layoutSubviews**
[image: referenceViewHierarchy]

As you can see, the whole UIButtonBarStackView seems to be shifted to the right. However, I can't figure out why that would be the case. Any help would be appreciated!